# C# Projection small model to big model

Tags: c#

I have 2 models:

```
public class People {

    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public DateTime Date {get;set;}
    public int Age {get;set;}
}
public class SmallPeople {

    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

And I have to do:

```
SmallPeople smallPeople = someData;
People people = smallPeople as People;
```

But I cant because vs shows error with conversion. How to repair this?

Comment: Your SmallPeople class needs to inherit from the People class, such as public class SmallPeople : People {}    Look up inheritance.

Comment: Yes but then my small people will have properties from People - all of view..

Comment: Then you have a design flaw. If a small person is a person, they automatically inherit all the properties of People.

Comment: There *is* a flaw in your design logic. Let's say you can actually do what you want (`people = smallPeople`). What values would `people.Date` and `people.Age` have?

Comment: The values is null

Comment: use inheritance or interfaces or a combination of both

Answer (score 0):

```
public class People
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class SmallPeople : People
{

}
```

There is no need to include Id and Name in your SmallPeople class because they exist in the parent class. If you want to be able to use a SmallPeople instance in an array of People, you need to inherit from People. It will pick up all properties from People.

```
SmallPeople smallPeople = someData;
People people = smallPeople as People;
```

Comment: Answer:  People people = Mapper.Map<SmallPeople, People>(model);

Answer (score 0):

The names of the classes can be anything, but I would inherit from small to large.

```
public class PersonRecord 
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Person : PersonRecord
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

This will allow you have an array of `PersonRecord` that are actually instances of `Person`. Attempting to go from `Person` to `PersonRecord` though is probably a code smell, but can easily be done using LINQ with `myRecordArray.OfType<Person>()`.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you rethink your approach and use inheritance. If you don't want to do inheritance, then you need to create a method to do what you need. Something like this:

```
public class People {

    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public DateTime? Date {get;set;}
    public int? Age {get;set;}
}
public class SmallPeople {

    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}

    public People ToPeople()
    {
        var people = new People();
        people.Id = Id;
        people.Name = Name;
        people.Age = null;
        people.Date = null;

        return people;
    }
}

var small = new SmallPeople();
small.Id="5";
small.Name="My Name";

var people = small.ToPeople();
```

Notice that I made `Date` and `Age` nullable so they can contain null values.

Answer (score 0):

Use serialization:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using Xunit;

namespace TestProjectionSmallModelToBigModel
{
    public class People
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
    public class SmallPeople
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class UnitTestProjectionSmallModelToBigModel
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Test1()
        {
            SmallPeople smallPeopleObject = new SmallPeople();
            smallPeopleObject.Id = "12345";
            smallPeopleObject.Name = "SomeName";

            string smallPeopleJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(smallPeopleObject, new JsonSerializerSettings() { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
            People peopleObject =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<People>(smallPeopleJson, new JsonSerializerSettings() { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });

            Assert.Equal(smallPeopleObject.Id, peopleObject.Id);
            Assert.Equal(smallPeopleObject.Name, peopleObject.Name);
        }
    }
}
```